Polars: pandas equivalent of selecting column names from a list
I have two DataFrames in polars, one that describes the meta data, and one of the actual data (LazyFrames are used as the actual data is larger):
import polars as pl
df = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["CX1", "CX2", "CX3"],
        "Sample1": [1, 1, 1],
        "Sample2": [2, 2, 2],
        "Sample3": [4, 4, 4],
    }
)

df_meta = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "sample": ["Sample1", "Sample2", "Sa,mple3", "Sample4"],
        "qc": ["pass", "pass", "fail", "pass"]
    }
)

I need to select the columns in df for samples that have passing qc using the information in df_meta. As you can see, df_meta has an additional sample, which of course we are not interested in as it's not part of our data.
In pandas, I'd do (not very elegant but does the job):
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(df_meta.query("qc == 'pass'")["sample"])]

However I'm not sure about how doing this in polars. Reading through SO and the docs didn't give me a definite answer.
I've tried:
df.with_context(
   df_meta.filter(pl.col("qc") == "pass").select(pl.col("sample").alias("meta_ids"))
).with_columns(
    pl.all().is_in("meta_ids")
).collect()

Which however raises an exception:
InvalidOperationError: `is_in` cannot check for String values in Int64 data

I assume it's checking the content of the columns, but I'm interested in the column names.
I've also tried:
meta_ids = df_meta.filter(pl.col("qc") == "pass").get_column("sample")
df.select(pl.col(meta_ids))

but as expected, an exception is raised as there's one sample not accounted for in the first dataFrame:
ColumnNotFoundError: Sample4

What would be the correct way to do this?

Just a note: with_context has been deprecated: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/16860

Just to build upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/78676922/ - I find require_all=False rather cryptic.
It is also possible to set intersect with the cs.all() selector:
>>> meta_ids = df_meta.filter(pl.col("qc") == "pass")["sample"]
>>> cs.all() & cs.by_name(meta_ids)
(cs.all() & cs.by_name('Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample4'))

df.select(cs.all() & cs.by_name(meta_ids))

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ Sample1 ┆ Sample2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
└─────────┴─────────┘


Either you have incorrect input (Sample4 is not in your input DataFrame) or you want to only select columns which have pass in df_meta DataFrame AND also exist in df DataFrame.

DataFrame.columns to get list of columns of df
set intersection (&) to find intersection of 2 lists of columns

passing_cols = df_meta.filter(pl.col("qc") == "pass").select(pl.col.sample).collect().to_series()

df.select(list(set(df.columns) & set(passing_cols))).collect()

┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ Sample1 ┆ Sample2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
└─────────┴─────────┘


The solution proposed is correct, but feels a little kludgy. A deeper look at the API docs showed that the by_name function from the selectors API has a parameter  (require_all) that suits the purpose:
import polars.selectors as cs

meta_ids = df_meta.filter(pl.col("qc") == "pass").get_column("sample")
print(df.select(cs.by_name(meta_ids, require_all=False)))

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ Sample1 ┆ Sample2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       │
└─────────┴─────────┘


Just a note, this one doesn't work with your example input - cause you have LazyFrame as an input, so you might need to either change input or syntax here a bit.
That's why I didn't use get_column but used collect of one column and to_series instead

Oh, right, I iterated over several options before settling for LazyFrame. I don't have the code in front of me here, but I'll adjust the answer tomorrow.
